# Unable to download file from url in C# and IE

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I'm trying to download file from below url in C# but it is not downloading instead it is showing file doesnot exists.But actually we are able to download file from chrome.

I'm using below code to this.

```
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    using (var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    {
        ...
    }
```

This code is working for some other urls but it is not working for above url. Can any one please help me what is the problem in above url and how to fix it?

Note : I'm able to download file from chrome but same url is throwing error in IE.
Thanks

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem description. What _does_ happen? Please read [ask].

Comment: C# is not a language that browsers understand, so please explain how we are supposed to jump from what you made in C# to something not working in IE.

Comment: I need to download file from url. The same code is working for some other urls but not this url. May be I need to encode or will have some other methods to download file from url. Please help me what's wrong in my code. How to use this kind of urls in c# to download files.

Comment: I assumed this code is in a controller. If your referencing the file, this obviously isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to the fact that IE tries to scan pretty much every download you make, and downloading from a relative URL (not a direct link to the file) through C# may cause some issues. Try downloading the file URL (`http://www.example.com/file.zip`), instead of relative (`http://www.example.com/hgrejr93yt734t022u`). If that doesn't work, check Fiddler and see what the response body says.

For future reference, please follow both mine and [@CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster)'s advice by asking properly (include error codes, response body, output, stack trace etc.).

Also, it's not the best idea to publicly post a link to your CV (the CV you've linked to has your phone number, city, email, passport, date of birth, AND qualification information). You've even uploaded an image to top it off :-).

Comment: An absolute URI that doesn't contain a file extension is not a relative URI. Any URI can return a file for download.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes but linking straight to the file may help. I'm just exploring all avenues :-)

Comment: `http://www.example.com/hgrejr93yt734t022u` _is_ (or can be) a straight link to a file. That the URI doesn't look like a filename doesn't matter in the slightest and most certainly doesn't matter for programmatically made HTTP requests. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah right. I didn't realise that :-). Guess you learn something new every day :D. Would this be the case in a C# web response through?